# How to read flags in GetHandleInformation function

Tags: c, winapi

I have a problem with GetHandleInformation function. Below there is source code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    char Nazwa[]="C:\\testfile.txt";
    BOOL test;
    DWORD dFlags;

    hFile=CreateFile(Nazwa,
                    GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    NULL,
                    CREATE_ALWAYS,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL |FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE | SECURITY_IMPERSONATION,
                    NULL);
    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            printf("Function CreateFile return error: %d\n",GetLastError());

    printf("File handle is OK\n");
    test=GetHandleInformation(hFile,&dFlags);
    //printf("%x\n",dFlags);
    printf("The return value is: %d, error: %d\n",test,GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    DeleteFile(Nazwa);

    return 0;
}
```

I try to read value of the flags in dFlags variable, but is still set as a 0.
Coul'd somebody tell me where is problem please. I tried to compare with HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT    or HANDLE_FLAG_PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE   but it doesn't work.

Comment: "*I try to read value of the flags in dFlags variable*" How?

Comment: Your program does not inspect dFlags

Comment: What is the output of your program ? Also there are logic errors in your program: You test if  `hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and if yes, the you display an error message, but then your program just continues with an invalid handle; you should stop the program instead.

Answer (score 2):

Zero is a completely valid value for `dwFlags`. If neither `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` nor `HANDLE_FLAG_PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE` are set, the flags will be 0.

What happens is, the `GetHandleInformation` function takes two parameters: the first is a handle to a file, and the second is a *pointer* to a DWORD. If the function succeeds, it fills in the second parameter with the flags. In your case, that would be your `dwFlags` variable. If the function fails, the value of `dwFlags` is undefined.

The *return value* of the function is what you are probably trying to check for a zero or non-zero value. Non-zero indicates success, whereas zero (`FALSE`) indicates failure. This is a `BOOL` value in Win32 terms. Note also that you can only expect `GetLastError` to return a meaningful value if the original function call failed (*i.e.*, returned `FALSE`). You should not call `GetLastError` if the original function call succeeded (*i.e.*, returned a non-zero value)!